# JavaScript Regular Expression About Numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

i have a input text which is a number only text that allows decimals length 3 but its not required to be a decimal number that the dot and the decimal numbers is not required to be there , that at least to be an integer number

Text

At least a 1 Integer Number

Max Integer Number Length is 2

At least 1 Decimal Number

Max Decimal Number Length is 3

Accepted Scenarios

"1"

"11.1"

"11.11"

"11.111"

I'm new in Regular Expression and this is as far as i can get

```
/\d{1,2}\.{0,1}\d{0,3}/;
```

Comment: Honestly, regex are something you have to study from the ground up. Your assignment looks pretty challenging. It is a school assignment, right? Take some time at http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html and you won't regret it. You can't be a serious programmer without regex in your toolbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows if I understand you correctly:

`^\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,3})?$`

### DEMO

Comment: your ans is the most perfect but i need 1 more thing that not to allow the . if there is no numbers after it and thank you very much for helping me

Comment: @Marwan, Yes that is what it does.

Comment: mmm i dont know does i write it right 

var d = /^\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,3})?$/mg;


d.test(11.);

Comment: i need to allow the . only if i have at least one decimal num after it

Comment: @Marwan, Wait, so `11.` ___is___ allowed or ___not___?

Comment: no not allowed :) what is allowed 1 , 11 , 11.1 , 11.11 , 11.111

Comment: @Marwan, Yeah. So you can see that it does _exactly_ that: http://regex101.com/r/sO4vL1

Comment: yeah so please help as far as you get is very great you look a regexp prof :)

Comment: @Marwan, I am __definitely__ willing to help. I just don't understand. You say it shouldn't match for that case. I showed you in my demo that it doesn't match for that case (just as you want). Isn't that problem solved. What is your query? I'm sorry if I'm not understanding what you're asking.

Comment: it helps thanks sshashank124 

Gazak Allah Khayran :) May God Give You The Most Of Good Things

Answer (score 1):

```
\d{2}d{3}\
```

is matching exactly two digits followed by exactly three minor d ... the final backslash might cause pattern compilation error or requests a backslash succeeding those sequence of d's.

```
\d{1,2}
```

is matching one *or* two decimal digits (0-9).

```
\d{1,3}
```

is matching one, two or three decimal digits.

If you need to match two different sequences you need to combine them using `|` in between:

```
\d{1,2}|\d{1,3}
```

However, this makes little sense, for the latter part is including the former.

```
\d{1,2}\.\d{1,3}
```

is matching two digits, succeeded by a period succeeded by one to three digits. But if period and its succeeding digits are optional as a whole, you need to group that first before declaring this group to be optional:

```
\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,3})
```

is grouping the latter part while

```
\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,3})?
```

is finally declaring that group to be optional.

If that's all to be matched in a string, you need to wrap it in anchors for matching beginning and end of string resulting in

```
^\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,3})?$
```